# Histogram of runs

Tags: date-and-time

What I would like to do is generate a histogram of the consecutive time spent under a level. For example if the level I was interested in was 1.0 and I had this data;

```
{{{2010, 1, 1, 6, 15, 0.}, 0.04375}, {{2010, 1, 1, 6, 30, 0.},0.04375}, 
{{2010, 1, 1, 6, 45, 0.},0.04375}, {{2010, 1, 1, 7, 0, 0.},5},
{{2010, 1, 1, 7, 15, 0.}, 0.5},{2010, 1, 1, 7, 30, 0.}, 5}}}
```

I would get a histogram containing two values, 45 (7:00am - 6:15am) and 15 (7:30am - 7:15am) minutes.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split time-series data based on a one-place test function, and collect total durations for spells of periods satisfying the test condition:

```
 ClearAll[durationsF];
 durationsF[timeseries : {{{__}, _} ..}, test_] :=
    With[{ts =  timeseries /. {{dt__}, val_} :> {AbsoluteTime[{dt}], test[val]}},
    (Last@# - First@#) & /@  Map[First, Split[ts, #[[2]] === True &], {2}]/60 /. 
      (0) ->  Sequence[]];
```

OP's example:

```
 opdata = {{{2010, 1, 1, 6, 15, 0.}, 0.04375}, {{2010, 1, 1, 6, 30, 0.},  0.04375},
   {{2010, 1, 1, 6, 45, 0.},  0.04375}, {{2010, 1, 1, 7, 0, 0.}, 5}, 
   {{2010, 1, 1, 7, 15, 0.},  0.5}, {{2010, 1, 1, 7, 30, 0.}, 5}};
 durationsF[opdata , # <= 1 &]
 (* {45, 15} *)
```

Weather data example:

```
 psdnWthr = WeatherData["Pasadena",  "Temperature", {{2012, 1, 1}, {2012, 1, 15}}];
 DateListPlot[psdnWthr, GridLines -> {Automatic, {15}}, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

```
 durationsF[psdnWthr, # <= 15 &]
 (* {180, 1200, 2460, 840, 480, 720, 120, 1980, 3840, 1020} *)
```

Notes: If the input time series is not sorted, use `ts=SortBy[ts,First]` in the function definition. For units of measurement other than minutes, multiply by appropriate factors.

Comment: Great. Execution time of 0.65 seconds on a 100,000 row data set is impressive.

Answer (score 3):

I assume that your information is sorted time-wise.

Save it as a symbol:

```
data = {{{2010, 1, 1, 6, 15, 0.}, 0.04375}, {{2010, 1, 1, 6, 30, 0.}, 0.04375}, {{2010, 1, 1, 6, 45, 0.}, 0.04375}, {{2010, 1, 1, 7, 0, 0.}, 5}, {{2010, 1, 1, 7, 15, 0.}, 0.5}, {{2010, 1, 1, 7, 30, 0.}, 5}};
```

Find the time spent on each step:

```
data2 = Prepend[
     #1, 
     DateDifference[First[#1], First[#2], "Minute"] // First
     ] & @@@ Partition[data, 2, 1]
(* {{15, {2010, 1, 1, 6, 15, 0.}, 0.04375}, {15, {2010, 1, 1, 6, 30, 0.},0.04375}, {15, {2010, 1, 1, 6, 45, 0.}, 0.04375}, {15, {2010, 1, 1, 7, 0, 0.}, 5}, {15, {2010, 1, 1, 7, 15, 0.}, 0.5}} *)
```

Split according to your criteria (`level`), then collect your desired result, in the format `{start time, end time, time spent on level}`

```
level = 1;
data3 = Module[{start, duration},
   Cases[Split[data2, Last[#1] < level && Last[#2] < level &], 
         x_ /; Last[Last[x]] < level :> 
            {
            start = x[[1, 2]],
            DatePlus[start, {duration = Total[First /@ x], "Minute"}], 
            duration
            }
        ]
   ]
(* {{{2010, 1, 1, 6, 15, 0.}, {2010, 1, 1, 7, 0, 0}, 45}, {{2010, 1, 1, 7, 15, 0.}, {2010, 1, 1, 7, 30, 0}, 15}} *)
```

Then, to plot it:

```
date = DateString[#, {"Hour", ":", "Minute"}] &;
BarChart[Last /@ data3, 
    ChartLabels -> ("From " <> date[#1] <> " to " <> date[#2] & @@@ Most /@ data3)]
```

> [image: Bar Chart]

Comment: You might consider using `AbsoluteTime[]` instead and divide by sixty to get the number of minutes...

Comment: @J.M. Why? Is it faster?

Comment: It's usually easier to manipulate absolute times than dates. You'll need to do your own tests tho.

Comment: The data set I have has about 100,000 rows so I'm not sure how practical this is. On my machine I get 95 seconds to do the data2= line.

Comment: @Cam as per J.M.'s suggestion, using `AbsoluteTime` and dividing by 60 speeds the whole thing up.

Comment: @VF1 thanks, changing to Absolute Time does indeed speed it up.

Comment: @Cam also, in mine, a great deal of the speed drag comes from the `Prepend`.  If you are looking for something along the lines of kluger's solution, where only the total times are shown (without the actual endpoints of the time spent), then you can get rid of the `Prepend` altogether, which in turn speeds the whole thing up even more.